# Save Using a UserForm, Error: can't show modally

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to prevent users from saving without using the naming conventions established in a Userform. Below is the workbook code:

```
Public Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
UserForm1.Show
If UserForm1.Visible = True Then
    Cancel = False
    Exit Sub
End If
Cancel = True
MsgBox ("Please use the save form.")
End Sub
```

I then have a button on the userform that should save the file containing the code:

```
Sub SaveButton_Click()
Dim FileName As String
    FileName = FileNameTextBox.Value
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileName
End Sub
```

Unfortunately this gives me a

> 400 error: "Can't show modally".

I am not sure what this means or how to resolve it. Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Try, please, `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`.

Comment: That works, however it immediately opens up the userform again and the only way to prevent it from looping is to exit out of the userform. Any ideas on why it is opening up again after saving?

Comment: Read the article I've linked to (note: it's all about *modal* forms), in particular the part about *default instances*. You need to `New` up that form and treat it like the object it is. How is the form being closed? It's important...

Comment: Is the form supposed to block execution of the calling scope (modal) or not (modeless)? It's unclear what behavior you're looking for, from your post.

Comment: Wait the form is shown and invokes a `Workbook.Save`, and then the `BeforeSave` handler is attempting to show that form again? That's why you can't show it modally - it's already visible and modal. Making it modeless isn't going to fix it, what you need is to de-tangle the logic. Best way to do this, is to make the form as stupid  as possible - it's not a form's job to run any kind of non-UI logic, like invoking `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`

Comment: So the reason behind having the 'If statements' is to force the user to use the userform to save. So i believe the answer to your question is 'modal', to block the execution of the calling scope. However I need the userform to be allowed to save the file.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I see what its doing now. Thanks for your help! @MathieuGuindon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UserForm1.Show` is showing the form modally - that means execution will only resume with the next instruction *after* the form has closed, and this implies `If UserForm1.Visible = True` will always be `False`... if you're lucky.

If the user closes the modal form with the red [x] button, then the object gets destroyed, and `If UserForm1` re-spawns a new one, and *that* instance will not be visible either (because it was never shown in the first place).

You could try showing the form *modeless*:

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```

Now execution will resume in this scope immediately after showing the form... making the condition `UserForm1.Visible` always `True`.

Remove `UserForm1.Show` from the `BeforeSave` handler: that handler's job is to cancel saving if the form isn't visible - *not to unconditionally display that form!* - you're getting this "can't show modally" error, because you're trying to show a modal form that's *already* modally displayed.

Read up on userforms and default instances on my [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) blog.